# Termo inicial de final da sequencia de fibonacci (intervalo fechado)

Tags: c, fibonnaci

Tenho que fazer uma lista de exercícios em C e Java, mas não consegui entender a lógica nesse exercício. Alguém poderia ajuda?

Solicite ao usuário o termo inicial e o termo final da sequencia de Fibonacci
(intervalo fechado) e imprima o resultado.

Ex:
    Sequencia de Finomacci → 0, 1, 1, **2, 3, 5, 8, 13,** 21, 34, 55, 89, …

Termo inicial → **4**

Termo final → **8**

Comment: Esta pergunta parece ser descontextualizada porque pede para resolver o exercício completo sem demonstrar suas tentativas, sem mostrar código próprio e sem dizer o que não entende sobre o problema de programação em si.

Answer (score 1):

A sequencia de Fibonacci e definida da seguinte maneira:

```
F(1) = 0
F(2) = 1
F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2), se n > 2
```

Ou seja, a sequencia comeca com os termos `0` e `1` e a partir dai os proximos termos sao a soma dos dois anteriores. Por exemplo:

```
F(4) = F(3) + F(2) = 1 + 1 = 2
```

O seu exercicio pede que o usuario entre dois parametros, `inicio` e `fim`. O que voce tem que imprimir sao os numeros `F(n)` para `n` entre os numeros `inicio` e `fim`. Por exemplo,se `inicio = 4` e `fim = 8`, como no seu exemplo, voce tem que imprimir `F(4), F(5), F(6), F(7), F(8)`.

Comment: Eu sei fazer a sequencia. Já fiz outros exercicios, mas não entendi como fazer esse aí. Porque vai imprimir a partir do 4º termo e terminar no 8º termo seguindo o exemplo.
Ele não vai mostrar o 0, 1, 1 .

Comment: Se voce sabe gerar a sequencia, e so colocar a impressao dentro de um `if`. Se o valor do termo esta dentro do intervalo imprima ele, caso contrario nao :)

Comment: quando chegar da faculdade tento de novo. tenho 3 listas pra fazer de C e Java. ainda bem que de C já estou terminando kk
mas valeu ae ^^